# Edit Only Permission but not (add/Delete)

Tags: sharepoint-addin

I want to give "Edit Only" permission on List Items to the user, Like user only can Edit the Item and will not be able to (Add/Delete) Items.

I've used default "Edit" permission but it is allowing user to Add and Delete items too.

Please suggest..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own Permission Level. This option is available in site permission at root site.

There you can get option to add/edit/copy permission level. Select what permission you need and create permission level. In your scenario you can copy "Edit" permission level and then in that copied permission level, remove add and delete permissions.

here is a technet article on same
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx

Comment: One thing more..if i have a some Groups like L1, L2, L3, L4...etc..   and some User from L2 Group has created some Item then only one level down (L3) Group will be able to see these Item not other groups...could you suggest what is the Best way to do it or Is it available as OOTB?